# open with sublime text( folder on windows)

Tags: sublimetext3

Is there any tutorial to recommend how to open a FOLDER with sublime text? It is on the web with some codes to do it, but did not include how to use it, what to make, what to open, what to edit, etc... Please can anyone tell me how to do it, step by step? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 ways:

1. Drag a folder from Explorer into the Sublime Sidebar (open the sidebar with **`View -> Side Bar -> Show Side Bar`** or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>K</kbd>,<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd>)
2. Use **`Project -> Add Folder to Project...`**
3. Make sure the Sublime installation folder (`C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3`, I think) is in your `%PATH%`, then use the `subl` command line utility included with the [latest public Build 3065](http://www.sublimetext.com/3).